# Variable works but undefined further down the code block

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a function that inserts (frozen) JSON objects into a MongoDB:

```
var result = null, OID = null ; 
...

var test = dbHandle.collection('TestItems') ;
result = prepareObject() ;
test.insert(result, {w:1}, function(err, item) {
    if (err) throw err ; 
    OID = ObjectID(item[0]._id) ;
    test.update({_id: OID}, {$set: { userName: socket.userName, state: 'Ready'} }, {w:1}, function( err ) {
        if (err) throw err ;
        test.findOne({ _id: OID }, function (err, loaded) {
            if (err) throw err ;
            socket.emit('newData', { data: loaded }) ;
        });
    }) ;
}) ;
```

This code works as I would expect. However, further down in my code I need to make use of both the OID and result object but they are always undefined. I know I must be doing something wrong but I do not know what. My background is in C++ and my approach makes sense to me, but this is my first venture into  JavaScript / NodeJS / MongoDB. I would be obliged if someone could point me in the right direction please.

As an example, when I later try to create a new object:

`var myObj = {Title: result.Title, TID: OID, Stuff:'More Stuff Here'} ;`

When this object is inserted in to the MongoDB both the Title and TID values are 'undefined', but my TestItems collection is correctly updated implying that OID has a value! Is this some form of Scope issue? I can't see how as the declarations, assignments and use are all in the same closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is most likely a problem of asynchronous design.
Your test.insert function gets what is called a "callback" function as third argument. This function will be called after insertion is complete, but the execution is not blocked by test.insert, so you might execute further code before the callback is called.

To give you a better image of what's going on, your script runs in this order:

- test.insert is called
- whatever follows after test.insert is called (you still don't have OID and result)
- (later) the callback of test.insert is called (where your OID and result properties are set)

What you can do is put the code where you want to use OID and test.insert in a function and call it from the test.insert callback:

```
result = prepareObject();
test.insert(result, ..., function(err, item) {
    // do stuff, get result objects, OID, etc
    // call your onInsertFinish function (pass result and OID to avoid using globals)
    onInsertFinish(result, OID);
});

function onInsertFinish(result, OID) {
    // do stuff with result and OID
}
```

Hope this helps.